# Mock with Mockito return a InvocationTargetException

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito, junit4

I'm writing some unit test and I stumble accross this strange "bug" which prevent me from running my unit test.

When I run the "when(...).thenReturn(...)", I receive a InvocationTargetException. Then strange things is that when I debug, it goes into the real object and crash on a null member. When I debug other "when", it goes in a function called "Intercept" which prevent to go in the real code... I don't understand what is different with this object and how to prevent this weird behavior.

Here is my unit test:

```
@Test
public void getSyncStatusShouldReturnValueFromDiskWhenNotRunning() throws IOException {
    //Arrange
    when(updater.isDone()).thenReturn(true);
    when(brandSyncUpdater.isDone()).thenReturn(true); //This is where it throw error
    when(stationSyncUpdater.isDone()).thenReturn(true);

    //Act
    //Assert
}
```

Here is my setUp() and member section of my unit class test

```
private Updater updater;
private BrandSyncUpdater brandSyncUpdater;
private StationSyncUpdater stationSyncUpdater;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    updater = mock(Updater.class);
    brandSyncUpdater = mock(BrandSyncUpdater.class);
    stationSyncUpdater = mock(StationSyncUpdater.class);
}
```

I don't know if it's related but the BrandSyncUpdater and StationSyncUpdater both have a parent called SyncUpdater where the isDone() function is located.

***EDIT***

**Hierarchy of class**

`Updater` is a class on its own

`BrandSyncUpdater` and `StationSyncUpdater` are extending `SyncUpdater`

`Updater isDone()` signature and code:

```
public boolean isDone() {
    return states.isEmpty();
}
```

`SyncUpdater isDone()` signature and code:

```
public boolean isDone() {
    return currentStates.isEmpty();
}
```

***EDIT 2***

Here is the stack traces of the error in the console. You'll notice that the error here is a "NullPointerException" because it try to use the variable `currentStates`. But when debugging, the error thrown by mockito is InvocationTargetException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.stingray360.clap.synchronizer.contentcontroller.queue.SyncUpdater.isDone(SyncUpdater.java:117)
    at com.stingray360.clap.synchronizer.contentcontroller.queue.BrandSyncUpdater.isDone(BrandSyncUpdater.java:15)
    at com.stingray360.clap.synchronizer.contentcontroller.SyncDispatcherTest.getSyncStatusShouldReturnValueFromDiskWhenNotRunning(SyncDispatcherTest.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
```

Comment: could you post the `BrandSyncUpdater` and `Updater` classes?

Comment: I can't since it's code from my job but if you tell me the things you want to know, I can post some parts or/and add information to my question. Like I said, Updater is working ok, it's the BrandSyncUpdater and StationSyncUpdater that throw the error when mocked.

Comment: Signature of methods and hierarchy of classes would be helpful

Comment: I added the requested informations.

Comment: Are you sure the class/method is not final? What is the exact and complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @JBNizet that was my first thought, but, if it were final, he would have got a `MissingMethodInvocationException` instead of an `InvocationTargetException`. Sorry @Jean-François Côté, I have no idea.

Comment: I added the stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the problem by error trying something else.

My `SyncUpdater` class wasn't public (it was package). So when trying to use Reflection, it got stuck and throw this weird error.

Thanks for the help of people in the comments!

Comment: Like I said, my class wasn't public, it was package access. As soon as I put the "public" back, it started to work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the same issue by adding the following code snippet to the test Class.

```
@ObjectFactory
public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
    return new PowerMockObjectFactory();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error. In my case i missed **@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)** for my Class (i know it is silly mistake, but wasted few hours troubleshooting everything else :) ).

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SimpleServiceUpgradeManagerTestNotUsed {
//Class content

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also met this kind of exception, the reason is I didn't initialize the class to which the method I mocked belongs.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with codes below

`catch (final HttpStatusCodeException e)`

**After I remove the *final* before HttpStatusCodeException, the Junit test works fine.**

And I just use Mockito, no PowerMock